# What are the naming conventions for custom Vue events?

Tags: vue.js

When using a named v-model like this:

`<my-component v-model:visible="visibleBoolean" />`

We use a special emit on the child component that looks like this:

`<button v-if="visible" @click="$emit('update:visible', false)">`

But that got me thinking about how I name my other events not tied to a v-model.

Should they also have a keyword like `update:` or something similar preceeding them?

I know it's not *required* for it to work, but I'm trying to understand defacto naming conventions.

For example, should `emit('my-custom-event')` have any preceeding keyword in the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`v-model`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#v-model-arguments) requires the updating event name to be `update:[PropName]`.
To avoid any potential conflicts, you should not use that `update:` prefix for your custom events that have no relation to `v-model`s. It's okay to use a different prefix if you want one.

Otherwise, the only naming convention Vue recommends is kebab-case for [event names used in DOM templates](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#event-names).

Comment: Do you personally use a prefix for your custom events? If so what keyword do you use? I know it might not be a naming convention documented by Vue but I figure there might be an unoffical way devs do this in the wild.

Comment: I personally don't use a prefix. That's not because I'm against it. I just have no reason to.